# Magento 2 | event before checkout#payment

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, event-observer

is there an event which gets fired before you get to checkout#payment?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question, and add some more information. Such as what you are trying to achieve with the event observer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this event sales_model_service_quote_submit_before but don't call save function in your observer